# Easy way for deploy helm chart and testing them?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm

I'm new to k8s.

**Now I have:**

k8s cluster with zero trust and testing immediately on it using git push and waiting for deployment via gitlab ci. Obviously, this is the wrong way.

**I would like:**

Test locally (using minikube?), with the ability to quickly see the changes (some hot reload for helm?). Raising a local cluster that is close to productive (zero trust and other things).

**Googled this problem and found:**

https://skaffold.dev/

https://github.com/garden-io/garden

**The essence of the question:**

I ask you to suggest the right solution.
Can the utilities above help with this problem?

Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additionnally to what you've found, you can have a local cluster up and ready with either of these solutions:

- [docker desktop](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/kubernetes/)
- [minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/)
- [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/)
- [microk8s](https://microk8s.io/tutorials)
- [k3s](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/)

If you have no other particular criteria than running a local cluster, pick any of the first 4 and test your charts locally. As your needs expand you'll get to compare them. For example, [you can setup k3s in gitlab CI](https://betterprogramming.pub/using-a-k3s-kubernetes-cluster-for-your-gitlab-project-b0b035c291a9) to test you cluster changes during the CI/CD process.

Answer (score 0):

Garden developer here!

You can definitely obtain the dev workflow you are after with Garden.

We have support for Helm via the [Helm module type](https://docs.garden.io/reference/module-types/helm) and you can also setup code syncing using [Dev Mode](https://docs.garden.io/guides/code-synchronization-dev-mode). You can find an introductory guide on using Helm with Garden in our [docs](https://docs.garden.io/guides/using-helm-charts).
There are a bunch of examples in the GitHub repository but I'd specifically recommend to take a look at [this](https://github.com/garden-io/garden/tree/master/examples/vote-helm).

The default provider configuration in the example project configuration is `local-kubernetes` which means you can use any locally-running cluster (for example the one shipped with [Docker Desktop](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop/)) and Garden should be able to pick it up automatically and deploy the project in there.

You can also specify a remote cluster and develop 100% remotely using Dev Mode, but keep in mind it requires additional setup (external registry, secrets for accessing the registry, and so on) and the detailed setup instructions are outside of the scope of the question.

I hope this helps!